# Swing - Awt. How do I render a new frame without the elements from the previous frame?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, 2d

I'm making a little game using the Swing and the Awt libs. [image: This is my frame.]

When I render a frame the Images I added through the paint() method from the previous frame stay there, my character, the green square, is the only mooving element.

How do I "clean" my JPanel before updating the game status and draw a new frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I render a frame the Images I added through the paint() method

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel` and you add the panel to the JFrame. And you make sure you invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first statement of the method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't invoke super.paintComponent(). Also, It takes as an argument a "Graphics" object.